# PyQT5 how to implement QTimer instead of time.sleep

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to implement a QTimer in place of the time.sleep: (line 25)

```
def fireOrder(self, fire_cord, fire_mode):
    if fire_mode == "normalFire":
        angelMils = "Out of range"
        baseUnits = calculator.getCordsBasUnits(fire_cord[0], fire_cord[1])
        if baseUnits[1] > 50 and baseUnits[1] < 1250:
            angelMils = calculator.milsCalc(baseUnits[1])
        self.textUpdateMain(baseUnits[1], calculator.angleDegNorth(baseUnits[2]), angelMils)
        return

    else:
        for i in range(1, len(fire_cord)):
            baseUnits = calculator.getCordsBasUnits(fire_cord[0], fire_cord[i])   
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, )
            angelMils = "Out of range"
            if baseUnits[1] > 50 and baseUnits[1] < 1250:
                angelMils = calculator.milsCalc(baseUnits[1])

            self.textUpdateMain(baseUnits[1], calculator.angleDegNorth(baseUnits[2]), angelMils)
            sleep(20)
        return
```

I have tried to implement a QTimersingleShot() function like this:

```
def fireOrder(self, fire_cord, fire_mode):

    if fire_mode == "normalFire":
        angelMils = "Out of range"
        baseUnits = calculator.getCordsBasUnits(fire_cord[0], fire_cord[1])
        if baseUnits[1] > 50 and baseUnits[1] < 1250:
            angelMils = calculator.milsCalc(baseUnits[1])
        self.textUpdateMain(baseUnits[1], calculator.angleDegNorth(baseUnits[2]), angelMils)
        return

    else:
        for i in range(1, len(fire_cord)):
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.update(fire_cord, i))
        return

def update(self, fire_cord, i):
    baseUnits = calculator.getCordsBasUnits(fire_cord[0], fire_cord[i])
    angelMils = "Out of range"
    if baseUnits[1] > 50 and baseUnits[1] < 1250:
        angelMils = calculator.milsCalc(baseUnits[1])

    self.textUpdateMain(baseUnits[1], calculator.angleDegNorth(baseUnits[2]), angelMils)
    return
```

But I get this error:

File "D:/SquadCalc2/SquadMortarCalc2/main_stelli.py", line 331, in update
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, )
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
singleShot(int, PYQT_SLOT): not enough arguments
singleShot(int, Qt.TimerType, PYQT_SLOT): not enough arguments

I am running out of ideas now and I have also tried to put the second argument of the time in a lambda
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: self.update(fire_cord, i))
but it didn't help.

The full code is over here:
https://github.com/Phoenix-64/SquadMortarCalc2/tree/area_fire_system

EDIT:
fire_cord is a list like:
fire_cord = [[10, 20], [-10, 10], [-10, -40], [30, 40]]

Comment: Why are there so many (doubled) empty lines in your snippets?

Comment: because I haven't formatted it yet.

Comment: @Phönix64 then, for future reference, please take some time to format at least the part that you're providing. Unnecessary empty lines make your code just hard and annoying to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with your lambda.  I'm assuming it worked but gave you the same value for i multiple times.  This is because there is only 1 lambda function instance and it was overwritten in each iteration of the loop,so all of the singleshot functions were pointing at the same one..the last one.

Also, I'm assuming you wanted them to fire every 2 seconds?  If so you'll need to multiply by i.

In place of lambda, try functools.partial.

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        fire_cord = [[10, 20], [-10, 10], [-10, -40], [30, 40]]        
        for i in range(1, len(fire_cord)):
                QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000*i, partial(self.update, fire_cord, i))

    def update(self, fire_cord, i):
        print(f'{fire_cord[i]=}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Yes, thank you it works. Could you explain what partial does?

Comment: Partial creates a new function with the values you provide it, or as the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html) says it “freezes” some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a new object with a simplified signature